# How to get the substring from a String in ColdFusion

Tags: string, coldfusion

How can I get the Substring in Coldfusion?

ex:- following is the String "Update Tablename  set value=something where value2=thisone"

I want to get the Table name from the Str

how is it possible?

Note:- Table name is dynamic(i.e may be any charecters).

Thanks

Comment: As Sabeen says, it sounds like you want a regular expression for this problem, but you'll need to provide more details on what you're trying to do before we can provide a good answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

updated:

You can probably use `result = ListToArray(sql , " ")` and then use the `result[2]`

also i believe you can do `ListGetAt(sql, 2, " ")`

Comment: Well, This works fine when I use Table name only in above QUery.

What about if i want to get "value" only in "value=something" or want to get "where value2=thisone" from the above query?

Comment: then my friend you will have to look into regular expressions to suit your needs. But again i don't think you would be able to have one solution for all scenarios.